# Disable Bluetooth hardware programmatically in iOS?

Tags: iphone, hardware, bluetooth, ios

How can I turn off the bluetooth hardware when I'm done with it so that my app does not drain the battery?

I've seen references to private frameworks but not how to do this in a way that will not get rejected by Apple.

What Framework/code do I need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, and you shouldn't be able. How do you know the user doesn't want to keep bluetooth turned on so they can pair with their handsfree kit, or their car. If I was using your app, and then I walked to my car, started it, got a phone call, and my handsfree didn't work I would be pretty annoyed. You don't own the device, and you don't know what the user is doing outside of your app.

Comment: There are cases where bluetooth devices would be paired with a specific application, so this would be a legal thing to do on a device by device basis.

Comment: you can always keep away from apps that get you "pretty annoyed" . this is not a reason to exclude an entire SDK especially when it is for something so useful as Bluetooth is.